# How do I fadeOut and fix the reset button here?

Tags: javascript, button, fadeout

```js
document.getElementById("shrinkBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {

  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "25px";

});

document.getElementById("growBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {

  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";

});

document.getElementById("fadeOutBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {

  document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "slow";

});
document.getElementById("resetBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {

  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px";

});
```

```html
<p>Press the buttons to move the box!</p>

<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:teal; margin:25px"></div>

<button id="shrinkBtn">Shrink</button>
<button id="growBtn">Grow</button>
<button id="fadeOutBtn">Fade Out</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

I added two buttons, but it broke the reset button.. What I truly need is:

```
<button id="growkBtn">Grow</button>
<button id="blueBtn">Blue</button>
<button id="fadeOutBtn">Fade Out</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css to create a fade-out effect by changing the class, and the reset button to change reset the class and height.

Also, you're using a wrong `id` in the resetBtn eventListiner, The `id` is `reset` while you're targeting `resetBtn`.

```js
document.getElementById("shrinkBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "25px";
});

document.getElementById("growBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
});

document.getElementById("fadeOutBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("box").className = "hidden";
});
document.getElementById("resetBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px";
    document.getElementById("box").className = "visible";
});
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<p>Press the buttons to move the box!</p>

<div id="box" class="visible" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:teal; margin:25px"></div>

<button id="shrinkBtn">Shrink</button>
<button id="growBtn">Grow</button>
<button id="fadeOutBtn">Fade Out</button>
<button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
```